# Bouncing effect in Farseer WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, farseer-physics-engine

I'm not quite sure what I need to do, but I have a ball falling from the sky and it needs to bounce when it hits an object. Do I configure the ball in some way or do I need to setup a spring object or possibly do something on collision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Requires a bit of tweaking but it works as I expect.

```
Body ball1 = PrefabBodtFactory.CreateBody(PrefabType.Ball, _world, new Vector2(3.8f, -0.75f));
            ball1.CreateFixture(new CircleShape(0.25f, 0.5f));
            ball1.FixtureList[0].Restitution = 1f;
            ball1.ApplyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0));
            _bodies.Add(ball1);
```

Comment: Care to mark this as the answer?

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs: He has to wait at least 2 days (I think) to do that.